# Running NodeJS server in virtual docker-machine - Cannot access running VM app

Tags: node.js, macos, docker, virtual-machine, virtualbox

I am going through [this](http://jdlm.info/articles/2016/03/06/lessons-building-node-app-docker.html) docker tutorial in order to get my [electrode](http://www.electrode.io/) app working in a VM.

When I run `node server.js` in the VM it logs a message indicating the Hapi server is running:

```
Hapi.js server running at http://10cc6b467731:3000
```

However, when I try to navigate to `http://10cc6b467731:3000` in my browser I am unable to access the app.

My initial thought was that the port forwarding is messed up. I went into my VirtualBox configs for this VM, but it still does not work:[image]

I also included port forwarding in my `docker-compose.yml` file, but to no avail:

```
chat:
  build: .
  ports:
    - '3000:3000'
  volumes:
    - .:/home/app/chat
    - /home/app/chat/node_modules
```

Now I am questioning if this is even a port forwarding issue at all. I am new to Docker and configuring VM's so I am not sure what direction to go in to continue troubleshooting this. What steps can I perform to confirm this is a port forwarding issue?

Comment: Have you tried `http://localhost:3000`?

Comment: @nash_ag Yeah, that does not work either.

Comment: 1. can you confirm you can access the docker app directly from the VM ? 2. in your forwarding port dont use the host 80 (its often reserved if you have web server running on your host), you can forward 3000 to 3000 for example

Answer (score 0):

You need to allow all IPs in node.js server code

add code like  `listen(3000, "0.0.0.0");`  in your node server.js